# Splitting Date and specially Time in C#. How to get the AM/PM thing

Tags: c#

I have the value as #7/13/2016 3:20:00 PM# And want to separate it out date and time. Format for date is "07/13/2016" and time is "03:20 PM". I have got the values with StartDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") and StartDateTime.ToString("HH:mm") but i am not sure about the "AM or PM" thing.

Comment: If you have a DateTime object, you can use the `TimeOfDay` and `Date` properties to get the time and day parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a DateTime value that you are trying to break into separate Date and Time. [Microsoft has great documentation on DateTime formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but I think what you are looking for for your time element is this:

```
SomeDateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

which should output "03:20 PM" or whatever the case may be.

Comment: Actually should use `hh` instead of `HH` as there's no point in having AM/PM with a 24-hour value which is what `HH` does.  So `HH:mm tt` would actually output "15:20 PM", not "03:20 PM".

Comment: @juharr using hh makes sense. Thanks